# The prefix "andriod" for attribute "andriod:name" associated with an element type "application" is not bound?

Tags: android, eclipse, attributes

I have a class by the name `G` which was extended from `Application`, this is the class :

```
public class G extends Application {

public static Context ctx;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();

    ctx = this.getApplicationContext();
  }  
 }
```

and in `AndroidManifest.xml` i added this class like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    andriod:name=".G"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".DatabaseTestActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

but it give me this error :`The prefix "andriod" for attribute "andriod:name" associated with an element type "application" is not bound.`

whats the problem ?

EDIT : this is my `AndroidManifest.XML` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="na.pe.database"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0" >

  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

  <application
    andriod:name="na.pe.database.G"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".DatabaseTestActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>

 </manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice, that there's a spelling mistake in your attribute name

```
andriod:name
    ^
```

Comment: this is my package name  =>  package="na.pe.database" ,  so , the  fully-qualified class name should be = na.pe.database.G ????

Comment: Yes, and `G` should physically be located in that package as well.

Comment: i do as u said , but it does not resolve the problem!

Comment: It gives me another error too :  Error parsing XML: unbound prefix

Comment: Please, post your manifest's root element. Have you specified the android namespace?

Comment: You have just mis-spelt the attribute prefix as *and-ri-od*.

Comment: And although the developer docs say otherwise, the dot notation should work too. I just tested in my local workspace.